# Does Java Evaluate a Variable Declared as Final only Once?

Tags: java, performance, debugging, compiler-optimization, final

I'm writing a Java program that requires thousands of `System.out.println()` statements that will be printed hundreds of millions (or billions) of times throughout the lifecycle of the program for debugging purposes:

```
if (GVar.runInDebugMode) System.out.println("Print debug message");
```

In the real world, these statements can be deactivated in order to speed up a computational heavy calculation.

If I set:

```
public final static boolean runInDebugMode = false;
```

Does the compiler re-evaluate `runInDebugMode` each time it comes across a statement like: `if (GVar.runInDebugMode)` or since it was declared as final it will be evaluated once at the beginning of the program and won't put additional strain on the CPU? In other words, would I be better off commenting out all debug statements entirely once I deploy the app or is setting `runInDebugMode`  to `false` sufficient?

Comment: If you're going to rebuild your project anyway (well, you'd have to do that to change a constant too), then maybe it doesn't matter, you just remove/comment the code. Or is the question to know how the JVM behaves in cases like this?

Comment: Are you asking whether the JIT compiler *makes asm that re-evaluates*?  The ideal situation is if the compiler itself evaluates the statement at (JIT)-compile time, and after that one-time work of handling the `if(false)`, eliminates dead code from the JIT-compiler output.  (Careful terminology is necessary here, because modern Java implementations compile at least twice: once source-> .class, then bytecode -> machine code, maybe redoing it if something that was previously true becomes false.  And in between they might interpret or might make first-pass less optimized native code.)

Comment: @ernest_k "Or is the question to know how the JVM behaves in cases like this?" Yes, exactly. I want to know how the JVM behaves. I'm aware I could comment/remove the code but if the performance will be EXACTLY the same (excluding the first evaluation of the variable) I prefer to keep the code the way it is and set `public final static boolean runInDebugMode = false;` to false..

Comment: @PeterCordes _The ideal situation is if the compiler itself evaluates the statement at (JIT)-compile time, and after that one-time work of handling the if(false), eliminates dead code from the JIT-compiler output._ Yes, this is exactly the question. I don't mind paying the price for the compiler to evaluate the statement once & then eliminate the dead code going forward as this essentially means basically no overhead during execution. My question is whether this is indeed how it works? Keep in mind the variable `runInDebugMode`  is being declared in a different class as `final static`..

Comment: When a JVM generates machine code at run-time (JIT), it can see all the `.class` files involved.  So cross-file inlining and constant-propagation is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a variable like

```java
public final static boolean runInDebugMode = false;
```

it’s a [*compile-time constant*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4).

> A *constant variable* is a `final` variable of primitive type or type `String` that is initialized with a constant expression ([§15.29](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29)).

[which means that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1-110-C)

> A reference to a field that is a constant variable ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)) must be resolved at compile time to the value `V` denoted by the constant variable's initializer.
>
> If such a field is `static`, then no reference to the field should be present in the code in a binary file, including the class or interface which declared the field.

In other words, when you write `if(runInDebugMode)` anywhere and `runInDebugMode` is `false` at compile time, the behavior is as if you’ve written `if(false)`, as the value must be resolved at compile time and no reference to the field appears in the compiled class file.

Your use case has been discussed specifically in [§14.22](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.22-300-ZA)

> However, in order to allow the `if` statement to be used conveniently for "conditional compilation" purposes, the actual rules differ.
>
> As an example, the following statement results in a compile-time error:
>
> ```
> while (false) { x=3; }
> ```
>
> because the statement `x=3;` is not reachable; but the superficially similar case:
>
> ```
> if (false) { x=3; }
> ```
>
> does not result in a compile-time error. An optimizing compiler may realize that the statement `x=3;` will never be executed and may choose to omit the code for that statement from the generated `class` file, but the statement `x=3;` is not regarded as "unreachable" in the technical sense specified here.
>
> The rationale for this differing treatment is to allow programmers to define "flag" variables such as:
>
> ```
> static final boolean DEBUG = false;
> ```
>
> and then write code such as:
>
> ```
> if (DEBUG) { x=3; }
> ```
>
> The idea is that it should be possible to change the value of `DEBUG` from `false` to `true` or from `true` to `false` and then compile the code correctly with no other changes to the program text.
>
> Conditional compilation comes with a caveat. If a set of classes that use a "flag" variable - or more precisely, any `static` constant variable ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)) - are compiled and conditional code is omitted, it does not suffice later to distribute just a new version of the class or interface that contains the definition of the flag.

So, this statement makes clear that this form of conditional compilation matches the intent of the language designers and that compilers are entitled to omit the code in question (all relevant compilers do). In principle, a compiler is not required to omit the code, but since it *must not* generate a reference to the field `GVar.runInDebugMode` in the compiled code, the code can’t contain a real conditional. If the code is not omitted, it must be skipped in a de-facto unconditional way. Either, by a `goto` instruction or, when compiling in the most naïve way imaginable, by literally testing `false`, `iconst_0; ifeq …`. Both approaches would be on the nanosecond scale in interpreted execution mode and no challenge to the JIT compiler/ optimizer at all.

---

It’s worth mentioning that `static final` fields are trusted fields which are normally not even changeable by Reflection. This is used, e.g. by the Assertion feature, as under the hood, a class containing an `assert` statement will have a `static final boolean` field initialized at class initialization time (so it’s not a compile-time constant) and each `assert` statement will skip its check conditionally, depending on the state of the `static final` variable. It was as early as at Java 1.4 time, when it was concluded that the necessary dead code elimination is commonplace in JVMs, to rely on it in this way.

So even if you turn your debug flag from compile-time constant to an initialization-time constant, the impact on the performance would be hardly noticeable. But the way you’re using it now, the code is removed at compile-time already and doesn’t rely on the JVM anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The scenario you have is described as "conditional compilation", i.e. the compiler that produces bytecode [can optimize away the code if the constant variable is false](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.22):

*"...in order to allow the if statement to be used conveniently for "conditional compilation" purposes, the actual rules differ.*

*As an example, the following statement results in a compile-time error:*

```
while (false) { x=3; }
```

*because the statement x=3; is not reachable; but the superficially similar case:*

```
if (false) { x=3; }
```

*does not result in a compile-time error. **An optimizing compiler may realize that the statement `x=3;` will never be executed and may choose to omit the code for that statement from the generated `class` file**, but the statement `x=3;` is not regarded as "unreachable" in the technical sense specified here."*

Note the part in bold: it depends on the compiler but it's quite easy to verify with the `javap` disassembler, just run `javap -v -l -p MyClass.class` to view the resulting bytecode. I'm pretty sure the Oracle/OpenJDK javac does that optimization since long ago and so do most compilers. Note that `GVar.runInDebugMode` is a [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29), so it benefits from this optimization.

###### Keep in mind:

*"Conditional compilation comes with a caveat. If a set of classes that use a "flag" variable - or more precisely, any static constant variable (§4.12.4) - are compiled and conditional code is omitted, it does not suffice later to distribute just a new version of the class or interface that contains the definition of the flag. The classes that use the flag will not see its new value, so their behavior may be surprising. In essence, a change to the value of a flag is binary compatible with pre-existing binaries (no LinkageError occurs) but not behaviorally compatible."*

which basically says that you have to also re-compile the code that uses the flag, in addition to the class that defines it. This shouldn't be a problem if you build the whole code.

Comment: It might be a good idea to be more explicit about the fact that your quotes from the standard apply even to static final values defined in other classes; [that seems to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71434304/does-java-evaluate-a-variable-declared-as-final-only-once/71466323#comment126310098_71434304) what the querent is worried about.

Comment: Your "keep in mind" section shows that the JLS at least *allows* Java compilers to do constant-propagation across classes at static compile time, not just at JIT time (on every run).  I wouldn't be surprised if real implementations only fully remove the dead code as they JIT in that case, but it's been a long time since I used Java and I forget whether `javac` looks at other `.class` files as it compiles.

Comment: @PeterCordes well, `javac` has to look at other `.class` files, as how would it find and verify the referenced members otherwise?

Comment: @PeterCordes There is no relevance to the fact that the constant is defined in another class. The important thing is that it's a constant expression, and hence benefits from code omission optimization.